# How to upgrade native libraries in system app in android

Tags: android, android-ndk

I have developed a system app for my rom which includes some native libraries.
I have tried below:

1. do not copy this native libraries into /system/lib, but let it in the apk. In this case, the libraries will not be copied to /data/data/xxxx/lib on system start and my app will failed to run since library can not found.
   (
   PackageManagerService.java 3301
   Note: We don't want to unpack the native binaries for system applications, unless they have been updated (the binaries are already under /system/lib). In other words, we're going to unpack the binaries only for non-system apps and system app upgrades.
   )
2. copy this libraries to /system/lib. My app run correctly first, but when I upgrade it, the new version of libraries will be copied to /data/data/xxxx/lib on start up. But since android will looking for libraries at /system/lib before /data/data/xxx/lib( In DexClassLoader::findLibrary),  the older version of libraries will always be loaded. It means that I will failed to upgrade native libraries then.

So, What should I do? Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

YOu can use `System.load()`, which use a full path parameter, to implement a different library search mechanism, in contrast to `System.loadLibrary()`. Below is a simple example:

```
public void loadLibrary(Context context, String libName) {
    String packageName = context.getPackageName();
    String libPath = "/data/data/" + packageName + "/lib/" + libName;
    if (new File(libPath).exists()) {
        System.load(libPath);
    } else {
        System.loadLibrary(libName);
    }
}
```

Comment: Sounds good, Thanks. While I have also found that this issue have been fixed in ics. ( in fact in honeycomb ).